# Autoware ROSBAG Demo no points_map

Tags: ros, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

my problem is that I do not get the expected output if I follow the instructions for the rosbag demo ([link](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/-/wikis/ROSBAG-Demo)), namely no `/points_map` is published by `my_map.launch` and also no tf between velodyne and base_link is present, thus also failing the detection.

Here the setup I am using:

- Ubuntu 18.04 + ROS Meldoic [Host], AMD Ryzen 7 3800X, Nvidia RTX 2070 super
- Docker (Version: 19.03.08) : autoware/autoware:latest-melodic-cuda

I uploaded a video of my steps: [link](https://youtu.be/d-c6YCQElEc).
Here are the commands I entered:

Host:

```
 mkdir -p ~/shared_dir   
 wget https://autoware-ai.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/sample_moriyama_data.tar.gz  
 wget https://autoware-ai.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/sample_moriyama_150324.tar.gz  
 tar zxfv sample_moriyama_150324.tar.gz     # also tried extracting in docker container
 tar zxfv sample_moriyama_data.tar.gz       # also tried extracting in docker container
 cd <path-to-autoware-docker-git>/generic && ./run.sh
```

Docker:

```
 mkdir -p ~/.autoware && cd ~/.autoware
 ln -s ~/shared_dir/data                             # also tried it with cp, made no difference
 ln -s ~/shared_dir/sample_moriyama_150324.bag       # also tried it with cp, made no difference
 roslaunch runttime_manager runtime_manager.launch
```

After running  roslaunch I followed instructions of [here](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/-/wikis/ROSBAG-Demo) / the video found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWwtr_71cqI)

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348637/autoware-rosbag-demo-no-points_map/) by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2020-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See: https://github.com/Autoware-AI/documentation/pull/6

---

Originally posted by [bfroemel](https://answers.ros.org/users/58010/bfroemel/) with karma: 36 on 2020-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) on 2020-08-21**:
Hey, I just pulled the docker image from hub and still have the same problem. Also changed the my_map.launch to match your commit.
Did you build autoware from source?
Thank you for your help

**Comment by [bfroemel](https://answers.ros.org/users/58010/bfroemel/) on 2020-08-22**:
Strange - replacing the my_map.launch file should be all it needs to get the rosbag demo working on the currently latest docker image (1.14.0). Could you verify your Autosar version:

```
git --git-dir=/home/autoware/Autoware/src/autoware/common/.git describe --tags
```

and that all files related to the demo are at the proper location (e.g., bin_Laser- pcd files in ~/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map)?
In the gnome-terminal window which pops up after launching the Autoware runtime manager you should see log messages regarding loading pcd files:

```
['roslaunch', '/home/autoware/Autoware/src/autoware/documentation/autoware_quickstart_examples/launch/rosbag_demo/my_map.launch']
pid=6999
sched policy=OTHER prio=0
load /home/autoware//.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00167_-00864.pcd
load /home/autoware//.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00153_-00852.pcd
load /home/autoware//.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00159_-00859.pcd
```

**Comment by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) on 2020-08-23**:
The default launchfile of 1.14.0 didn't work for me (checked the version with your command).
Needed to change it to your pr rebuild with
`AUTOWARE_COMPILE_WITH_CUDA=1 colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select autoware_quickstart_examples --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` and then fire everything up.
Now on the first start rviz won't show me the pcl, I always need to restart it.
Thanks for the help